# Cloning Ubuntu from one device directly to another device

Tags: disk-cloning

my colleague is recently asking me how can he clone a Ubuntu 20.04 SSD disk to another new device using M2 or NVME disk and run all programs and data in new device. What software can be used to make this work ? Or is it possible to connect both devices via LAN cable to make it work easier and faster. I am not familiar with Ubuntu or Linux. Any one can help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I do this whenever needed by using virtual machines and then just moving the machine. Very simple to do. Any VM (Linux or Windows).

Comment: Is there any url link that I can review and follow !

Comment: Not really (basic VM function).  Make a machine using VMware and that makes a VMDK machine file in a folder. The folder can be moved to another machine. I do this to back up machines and to change to a new computer.

Comment: Cloning to a different device will involve drivers, might not work, and is normally fraught with problems (broken machines that have to be reinstalled).

Comment: @john, can you give an example of that, in the last 5 or 10 years? Most DE *nix installs, and ubuntu especially are rather bloated with compatibility, so I'd be frankly stunned if moving from one machine to another broke it to the point of re-installation.

Comment: I have used virtual machines for more than 10 years and only cloned from one machine to the same machine (not a different machine).

Answer (score 2):

The comments have offered other solutions to your problem but to answer your question you can use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) to clone the existing SSD to another drive. There is a good guide [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-use-clonezilla/) to do it yourself, you want to do `device-device` and `drive-drive`. As far as running a LAN cable, that wouldn't be necessary if you're using Clonezilla since both drives will be plugged into the same device for cloning.

Concerns about drivers working on different hardware is somewhat warranted, but drivers in Linux work much the same as Windows where it is either precompiled in the kernel, or loaded as a module if needed (even proprietary drivers). [Ubuntu makes it easy as well](https://www.howtogeek.com/213488/how-to-install-hardware-drivers-on-linux/).

If you're interested in using a VM instead, Ubuntu has [their own guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox#1-overview) to set it up using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). You can also refer to [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/502059/create-virtual-disk-from-existing-hard-drive) if you want to create a VM from the disk.

Comment: Thanks. Clonezilla has options to use and not difficult to use. Tks.

Comment: @VB88 I'm glad you got it working, you can accept this answer by pressing the check mark under the vote down button!

Answer (score 0):

Disk cloning is very simply achieved with `dd`
For all the information you could possibly require `man dd` will provide, from your linux env.

The post-cloning steps will depend on your the environment it's being deployed in, but will generally be limited to generating new UUID, updating `fstab` and pointing your boot loader to same.

Comment: `dd` will waste some time and SSD write cycles by copying contents of unused disk space. I think there may also be problems if disks have different sector sizes, but don't quote me on this. Clonezilla or other software dedicated for this task will be faster and more user-friendly.

Comment: Valid comment, mitigated by `conv=sparse` switch. Not sure what the actual backend on clonezilla is, but as usual I wouldn't trust windows or windows software with a *nix file system.

Comment: `conv=sparse` would work for zeroes, but almost certainly there are some remains from deleted files that aren's 0s. Clonezilla won't copy them because it understands filesystems. It's Linux-based and uses `partclone` for copying/imaging by default, falling back to `dd` when an unknown filesystem is found.

Comment: Well the drive could be zero'd out first, but that's back to "wasting SSD write cycles" (If that's even a concern here). At any rate, since there is linux, I don't know why you'd add windows to the situation.

Comment: I don't think I've mentioned Windows anywhere?

Comment: DD also works. Tks